# Python3 wont install in the correct location

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation

I am trying to move to python3, but when I download python3 from the official website, it seems to be installing in the wrong place. The version is installed at

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/
```

while all other versions of python (python 2.3 - 2.7) so far are installed at

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions
```

I am able to access the python 3.6 interpreter via pycharm by setting the interpreter as 3.6 in the settings. But when using other programs such as sublime, the same code does not work when executed within a terminal within, because it seems to be using python 2.7 by default. Also the installed packages which I can access via pycharm do not work in sublime.

when executing

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

i get

```
['/Users/dominiquepaul/xJob/Youtube Tutorials', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC']
```

which appears to be to confirming that it is trying to use the old python as it only references python 2.7 folders

I've tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/320996/how-to-make-python-program-command-execute-python-3) and a few other things but nothing seems to work

**What do I have to do be able to use the installed version of python3 by default in all programs?**

Might it be an issue that for same reason the folder "library" exists twice with not the same files being inside?
That is as:

```
/library
```

as well as

```
/system/library
```

Being new to python and a bit frustrated because I cant get it to run, I appreciate every help. Thank you very much :)

Comment: I don't think it is wise to override the default system python. There are libs and other apps that use it. Python3 is NOT compatible to Python2.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. So, if I am not wrong, you want Python 3 to be your default version so that it can be used everywhere possible in your system. 
So, I would recommend you to first Uninstall your Python 3. 
Go to www.python.org
Select Python 3 version
Download the setup.
Start with the installation.
As soon as you start, you get a window where you are asked to set path by default. I have used the same image. 
Just select that check box.
Continue with the installation.
Once you are done, by default Python 3 has been set for your system.
Check the path now. 
I hope this works.

[This is the installation window.You need to select the last check box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCQQt.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is wise to override the default system python. There are libs and other apps that use it. Python3 is NOT compatible to Python2.

Instead of overriding your default `python` prompt call your scripts with `python3`.

Add a header at the very top of your files

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

If a file is executable (and executed) then the system will chose python3 or the specified version.

For sublime there are fields in the package configs where you can set your default python (e.g.):

```
"python_interpreter": "/usr/bin/python3",
```